# simple example for getting google access token using oauth2.0 java

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I want to fetch google analytics data using google access token, but i didn't find any example , i am getting "Exception in thread

> "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

error , below is the code:-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.AnalyticsReporting;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.DateRange;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.Dimension;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.GetReportsRequest;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.GetReportsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.Metric;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.ReportRequest;

public class AnalyticsApiTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
                .fromStream(new FileInputStream(new File("d:\\clientsecretnew.json")))
                .createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"));
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        AnalyticsReporting analyticsReporting = new AnalyticsReporting.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("testing_analytics")
                .build();

        DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
        dateRange.setStartDate("2017-06-11");
        dateRange.setEndDate("2017-06-13");

        // Create the Metrics object.
        Metric sessions = new Metric()
            .setExpression("ga:pageview")
            .setAlias("sessions");

        //Create the Dimensions object.
        Dimension browser = new Dimension()
            .setName("ga:browser");

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
            .setViewId("ga:152411###")
            .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
            .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(browser))
            .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));

        ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
        requests.add(request);

        // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
        GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest()
            .setReportRequests(requests);

        // Call the batchGet method.
        GetReportsResponse response = analyticsReporting.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();


    }
}
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong in this??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try following [Googles tutorials](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-java).   This is the code i use `ga:pageview` is not a valid metric its `ga:pageviews`

My Code:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.AnalyticsReporting;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.AnalyticsReportingScopes;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * @author Linda Lawton
 */
public class ReportingSample {

    /**
     * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
     * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
     */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "DAIMTO Google Analytics Reporting V4 sample";

    /** Directory to store user credentials. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
            new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/reporting_sample");

    /**
     * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
     * globally shared instance across your application.
     */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private static AnalyticsReporting service ;

    /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
    private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        // load client secrets
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
                new InputStreamReader(ReportingSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));

        // set up authorization code flow
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
                Collections.singleton(AnalyticsReportingScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY)).setDataStoreFactory(
                dataStoreFactory).build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
            // authorization
            Credential credential = authorize();
            // set up global Analytics instance
            service = new  AnalyticsReporting.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                    APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            // run commands

            fetchData(service);
            // success!
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }


    public static void fetchData(AnalyticsReporting service) throws IOException{

        DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
        dateRange.setStartDate("2017-06-11");
        dateRange.setEndDate("2017-06-13");

        // Create the Metrics object.
        Metric sessions = new Metric()
                .setExpression("ga:sessions")
                .setAlias("sessions");

        //Create the Dimensions object.
        Dimension browser = new Dimension()
                .setName("ga:browser");

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
                .setViewId("ga:78110423")
                .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
                .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(browser))
                .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));

        ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
        requests.add(request);

        // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
        GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest()
                .setReportRequests(requests);

        // Call the batchGet method.
        GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();

    }
}
```